# How to propagate header values with different header names using sleuth/brave

Tags: trace, spring-cloud-sleuth, brave

I would like to propagate the `request-foo` header value received in a service (foo) to another header `header-bar` for service (bar). I would like to leverage sleuth/brave instrumentation for this without including it into the business logic

`foo-service --------> HTTP ------> bar-service
(request-foo)                     (request-bar)`

There is already support in Sleuth and Brave for propagation when the header names match. For example by setting in the `foo-service` the following

`spring.sleuth.propagation-keys=request-foo`

This would propagate the `request-foo` header value to `bar-service` with the `request-foo` header name.

Unfortunately, in my case, I have no control over the `bar-service` and it expects the header value as `request-bar` and also no control to rename `request-foo` header name because the `foo-service` receives it also from an upstream service.

I was thinking to provide an `Injector` similar to the `ExtraFieldInjector` but is not extendable the `ExtraFieldPropagation`, so I would need to provide my own `Propagation` implementation.

Wondering do I miss something? Is there an easier approach?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand. It should be enough to pass the extra propagation and it should be put in the headers. Is it not working?

Comment: Yes, it works if the header names are the same. In my case the header names are not the same, the bar-service expects the header value as request-bar and the foo-service receives the value in the request-foo header. How to propagate this way the correlation id?

Comment: You can create your own HttpParser bean and parse the request in the way you want to